# Windows 10 Twice on same machine (again)

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, uefi

Windows 10 v1709 wouldn't update to v1803, so downloaded OS image, disconnected SSD with v1709 installed, and did custom clean install of v1803 to new SSD formatted as GPT. Verified new v1803 working, and reconnected SSD with v1709.

Both versions working fine, but I cannot choose a boot option at startup except via UEFI. (I need to retain the old version until I have completed re-installing all my apps to the new one).

Is it possible to get the system to display boot-up options without having to go via UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. Both installations are on separate drives with separate partition tables and separate boot partitions.

At boot, UEFI has to identify which system disk is designated as bootable so it can hand off operations to the operating system boot loader.

Dual booting is usually accomplished by installing both operating systems on the same drive (or drive array, for RAID applications) so that the operating system boot loader is aware of multiple operating systems.